# Deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*': Can't use the constant

Tags: c++, string, char, deprecated

```
char *name[]={"Riyaz","Kapil","mayank","Ankur"};

int len=0;
len=strlen(name[1]);
cout<<"\n String 2 is   "; puts(name[1]); cout<<"\n and string 3 is";puts(name[2]);
//exchange now//
char *temp;
temp=name[1];
name[1]=name[2];
name[2]=temp;
len=strlen(name[1]);
cout<<"\nExchanged string is  "; puts(name[1]);
return 0;
```

How can I remove *"deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'"* warning in this code?

I was trying this program on array of pointers actually, so suggest some changes considering that.

Answer (score 7):

Just declare the array like

```
const char *name[]={"Riyaz","Kapil","mayank","Ankur"};
^^^^^
```

Opposite to C in C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays that in expressions are converted to pointers to their first elements. Though in the both languages string literals are immutable.

Correspondingly variable `temp` also must be declared like

```
const char *temp;
```

Take into acount that these declarations

```
const char *name[]={"Riyaz","Kapil","mayank","Ankur"};
```

and

```
const char * const name[]={"Riyaz","Kapil","mayank","Ankur"};
```

differ.

The first array is not a constant array. Its elements can be changed and you do that in your program. While the second array is a constant array. Its elements may not be changed.

As for the program then instead of this code snippet

```
const char *temp;
temp=name[1];
name[1]=name[2];
name[2]=temp;
```

you could use standard function `std::swap` declared in header `<utility>`. For example

```
#include <utility>

//...

std::swap( name[1], name[2] );
```

Comment: ... and, for output, `cout << "\nExchanged string is  " << name[1];`

Comment: Modifying the elements of a string literal is undefined behaviour in both C and C++.

Comment: @rubenvb  I am sorry but I have not understood why you wrote this your comment. And why did you downvote the answer?

Comment: @Vlad: My mistake. Carry on.

Comment: well thanks everyone for the answer .. got my doubt cleared :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you marked the question as **C++** (not C), you may want to use convenient **C++ classes** to build a string array, like a **`std::vector<std::string>`**:

```
#include <string>  // for std::string
#include <vector>  // for std::vector

// Old C-style:
// const char *name[]={"Riyaz","Kapil","mayank","Ankur"};
//
// C++ style:
std::vector<std::string> names{ "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", ... };
```